# Setting a default tab in Android?

Tags: android

In my application I have a `tabHost` with 5 tabs. And I want to set one of them (HomeTab) as my default tab, so every time I press 'BACK' when I'm on the "top view" of some other tab, I want to return to the Home Tab. What is the wise way to do this? To control states I use static variables. Do I have to put some `if` statement and check if the current tab is a Home Tab? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of this but it sounds like you want and need to override the default action of the 'back' button. Careful in doing this as it may be that you're doing something your users don't expect.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, currently I'm overriding the `onKeyDown` method on every top view of non-Home tab, and set the tab in TabHost to HomeTab. I was just interested, if it's the only way of doing my task...

Comment: Overring `onBackPressed()` as Kerubu recommends is undoubtedly the preferred way of doing this, as not all devices have hardware 'back' buttons (like Honeycomb tablets, which have the back-button on-screen), and therefore `onKeyDown` will never be called.

Comment: Oh, the application is not oriented on tablets, but thanks for advice! I will keep this in mind.